# Save data to .txt file and depend on it decide text of button

Tags: php, laravel, text-files, isset

I am new to laravel and php. I am trying to click on button and depends on text of the button, save to .txt file true or null. Then in controller get content from .txt file and use function isset to decide if in .txt file is true or null. And depending on this value  set text of the button on Add to shopping cart or Remove from shopping cart.

```
@if ($bool == True){
<button onclick="doSomething()" class="corner" id="test">Remove from shopping      cart</button>
} @else{
<button onclick="doSomething()" class="corner" id="test">Add to shopping cart</button>
}
@endif

<script>
    function doSomething() {
        var x = document.getElementById("test");
        if (x.innerHTML === "Add to shopping cart") {
            x.innerHTML = "Remove from shopping cart";
            <?php
            $handle = fopen($file, "w");
            fputs($handle, "true")
            //fclose($handle)
            ?>
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Add to shopping cart";
            <?php
            $handle = fopen($file, "w");
            fputs($handle, null)
            //fclose($handle)
            ?>
```

This is my show.blade.php code from some reason if I uncomment fclose($handle) I will get error.

```
$file = "added.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$bool = isset($current);
return view("products/show", compact( "bool", "file"));
```

This is my controller function in controller which display it. But in the end the button text after refresh or reopen is always Return from shopping cart. Anybody knows what is the issue?

Comment: Why use a .txt file to store such data? I assume you have multiple users/carts? Should they all save into the same .txt file? Why not use sessions?

Comment: I tried it with sessions. After the if statement instead of adding to .txt file I had $_SESSION["add"] = "true" and after else I had $_SESSION["add"] = null and bool had defined $bool = isset($_SESSION["add"]); and everything else same. But it had exactly opposite problem, when I refresh page there is always Add to shopping cart.

Comment: Did you check what was in your .txt file? You can't mix clientside and serverside code like you did. PHP is run on the server, it doesn't know about anything going on clientside, so your PHP code inside the JS `if`s will most likely not do what you think it does. `fputs($handle, null)` for example will _always_ be run! You would use AJAX to "control" PHP variables

Comment: The file is empty all the time, but the function isset is always true so I am confused. I don't fully understand your answer. Is there any way easy how can I fix it with .txt file or sessions?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Use sessions. Don't mix PHP inside JS. Use AJAX to change PHP variables/data from JS. Maybe don't use JS in the first place, this should all be doable using Blade only

Comment: brombeer I asked how to write this just in blade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288759/after-clicking-button-depending-on-text-change-button-text-in-php        and nobody gave me clear answer.

Comment: Be patient. You asked this only 1 hour ago and the fact that you're still mixing PHP inside JS tells me you haven't fully grasped the concept of HTTP requests/how server- and client-side works. Take baby steps, feels like you are trying to run before you can walk. Maybe take a fresh start, start a new project, try to simply get a button to change text depending on a session variable for multiple users only using Blade. Expand from there. If you have a deadline hire a freelancer. Take a look at how other projects implement shopping carts. Good luck!